# Block element inside table exceeds it parent size

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I am working on constructing HTML designed for Mail Clients using inline styles and a lot of `<table>`s.
While experimenting with tables I encountered the following phenomena -

Nested inside a `<td>`, a block element such as `<p>` or `<div>` will, as expected, take 100% of `<td>` parent width, unless its width attribute is declared explicitly.

For example:

The following code is a simple `<p>` element nested inside a `<table>`'s `<td>`. The `<table>`'s width is 700px and the `<p>` element with 50px padding is taking the `<td>`'s full width, no problem:

```
<div style="border-style: solid;">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700" style="width: 700px; background: red;">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p style="padding:50px; border-style: solid; border-color: blue;">something</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwXQXY?editors=1000

When explicitly giving the `<p>` element width of 100%, its size increases, but for some reason exceeds its `<td>` parent size:

```
<div style="border-style: solid;">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700" style="width: 700px; background: red;">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p style="padding:50px; border-style: solid; border-color: blue; width: 100%;">something</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNOZbV?editors=1000

Then, when applying "box-sizing: border-box" to the `<p>` element it aligns itself with `<td>` parent:

```
<div style="border-style: solid;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700" style="width: 700px; background: red;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p style="padding:50px; border-style: solid; border-color: blue; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;">something</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNOGyQ?editors=1000

As you can see, stating width of 100% makes the `<p>` tag exceed the `<td>` size. I first thought maybe the `<p>` inherits the old box model property from its `<td>` parent, but a) I didn't see it written in the browser's developer tool and b) if it did inherit it, then it should have exceeded the `<td>`'s size from the beginning because of the padding.

Would love to get an understand what's happening here

Comment: In Firefox 45.0.1 `<p>` fits perfectly in the `<td>` (last example code)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, Indeed, on the last example code it fits, since I added the box-sizing:border-box style that seems to solve the issue. The question is why does it happen in the first place - why would a 100% width break the alignment with parent and require adding this box-sizing style

Comment: The total width of an element is the following rules: `width + padding + border = total width`. If you change the model box with `box-sizing:border-box` , paddings and borders doesn't affect to the total width, so the `width = total width` but with paddings and borders applied. You must to search in google next time, there are tons of documentations about `box-sizing`, that explains you in few seconds, and in stackoverflow is full of this questions (duplicated and closed). https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Because in the first example you didn't specify a width what gives it the default value `auto` what makes the browser calculate the width. In the second example you give it 100% and the default value for box-sizing which is `content-box` this calculates 100% + padding + border.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, I read about the box-sizing, but the question remains - why the behavior seem to changes once the width attribute is added, even though the box-sizing remains the same. I might rephrase the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @lionHeart it doesn't change. I don't understand your new question.

Comment: Oh yeah, I catch it now. I think your problem is that you don't understand fine the difference between block elements and inline elements. Block elements are 100% of width by default since you don't specify a width, and in this case the behaviour is calculated automatically as box-sizing works. If you specify a width it changes.

Answer (score 1):

The initial `box-sizing` value means the `padding` and `border` add to the overall width.

The padding is 30px on the left and right, and the border is 3px on the left and right, meaning your overall width is 100% + 30px + 30px + 3px + 3px, which is 66px larger than the 100% width of the `td` element itself.

Comment: I think there's tons of questions in S.O. and tons of articles in google to provide another answer (N-plicated zillions of times).