# A div <div> element within a table exceeds a cell <td> margin

Tags: html, css

I encountered a strange behavior of HTML and CSS which I would normally not expect. Is someone able to explain this and may provide an idea how to overcome the problem.

The size of an div element within a table cell is not constrained by its container.

```
<style>
  table{
    width: 80%;
  }
  #text_status_line{
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
</style>
<div>
  <table>
      <tr id="text_status_row">
        <td style="border: 1px solid red;">
          <div id="text_status_line">Some text</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

As can be seen in the picture below the gray background of the div content exceeds the red border of the cell container (tested with Firefox and Chrome), which I would never expect. Because of this you run into great difficulties if you try to develop a table layout of a web page.

Any idea how to fix it?
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/yomf75np/

Comment: Get rid of `width: 100%;`. That, plus your margins and padding, exceeds the containing box. Read up on the box model.

Comment: Maybe dupe of [Block element inside table exceeds it parent size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36425277/215552)

Comment: This question is a duplicate indeed. Unfortunately I couldn't find the other answers before. Now that I've studied the other entries and the `box-sizing` property, I'm glad having learned from @Keyan about `width: inherit;` right here.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and simplest solution is to:

change:

```
    #text_status_line {
        margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
```

To:

```
    #text_status_line {
        margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        width: inherit;
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
```

which will make it inherit the width!

Answer (score 0):

Remove width in #text_status_line altogether.

```
table{
  width: 80%;
}
    #text_status_line{
        margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
```